# Terraform Path Issues in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terraform, devops

I wanted to setup Terraform locally on my Ubuntu 20.04 and I did it using the usual way where I wanted all my softwares to be installed in the /opt/softwares folder that I have.

I downloaded Terraform zip, unzipped it into /opt/softwares/terraform folder:

```
joesan@joesan-:/opt/softwares$ sudo ls -la
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 11 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 26 09:14 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 root   root    4096 Jul 18 21:56 ..
drwxrwxr-x  6 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 17 18:49 apache-maven-3.6.3
drwxrwxr-x  3 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 18 19:50 aws
drwxrwxr-x  8 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 17 18:50 idea-IC-201.8538.31
drwxrwxr-x  2 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 18 12:45 kubectl
-rw-rw-r--  1 joesan joesan 51798 Jul 18 14:18 .kubectl_aliases
drwxr-xr-x  3 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 18 13:14 minikube
drwxr-xr-x  6 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 17 19:24 rustup
drwxrwxr-x  4 joesan joesan  4096 Jun 28 00:07 sbt
drwxrwxr-x  6 joesan joesan  4096 Jun 25 22:59 scala-2.13.3
drwxrwxr-x  2 joesan joesan  4096 Jul 18 16:05 terraform
joesan@joesan-:/opt/softwares$
```

Inside this terraform folder is a binary executable terraform. I then set this path to my bash_profile as below:

```
export TERRAFORM_HOME="/opt/softwares/terraform"
export PATH="$SBT_HOME/bin:$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$KUBECTL_HOME:$TERRAFORM_HOME/terraform:$MINIKUBE_HOME:$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
```

But seems that is not enough as I get this message:

```
joesan@joesan-:~$ terraform --version
bash: terraform: command not found
joesan@joesan-:~$
```

Any ideas what the issue is? I thought it was straight forward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some confusion with your variables.

In your `PATH` you are referring to `$TERRAFORM_HOME`, but `$TERRAFORM_HOME` is not defined (at least you are not showing what is it).

Maybe it should be `$TERRAFORM_PATH`?

Comment: Sorry! That was a type! I now corrected it, but the problem is still there! I could not run terraform from command line yet!

Comment: @sparkr Hi. Now in you path you have: `/opt/softwares/terraform/terraform`? is that correct? You have folder `terraform` in folder `/opt/softwares/terraform`, thus full path to executable is`/opt/softwares/terraform/terraform/terraform` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the envirnoment variables from the profile file: `source ~/.profile` and then run again the terraform from command line.